# Googlecast receiver for Linux

Tags: linux, chromecast

I have a Linux nettop that's connected to my TV via HDMI.

I'd love to cast videos of Youtube, dailymotion, vimeo, OK.ru apps (or from any site supported by [youtube-dl](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html)) from my smartphone to my Linux nettop.

I know the Googlecast client protocol has been reverse engineered because there are software such as mkchromecast, castnow, etc., but I didn't find any Googlecast server software for Linux.

Do you know any (even experimental)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try installing kodi (xbmc) on your linux  machine, start it, enable all remote access functions etc in kodi. Then theoretically one can cast to it over dlna from android phone ( https://cormang.com/2018/06/30/how-to-stream-or-cast-from-android-to-kodi/amp/) and i think kodi also used to support air play.

Comment: I'm looking for a chromecast protocol receiver. Do Kodi support the chromecast protocol ?

Comment: @SebMa you mean Google Cast? I thought it’s proprietary , you need to buy google chrome cast for this. most of alternative cast solutions use alternatives such as DLNA (All cast etc which smart TVs often use).The best thing i’ve seen for linux was RaspiCast app, for raspberry pi, which uses ssh to launch youtube etc from android phone on the TV connected to your raspberry pi board. however it is using omxplayer to play gpu accelerated video  on pi, which exist only for raspberry pi .

Comment: https://youtu.be/4HC_0pkGOjw —- how to cast to kodi

Comment: How about other sites supported by [youtube-dl](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html) such as dailymotion, vimeo, ok.ru ?

Comment: @SebMa if you ask about kodi, it takes 2 min to test if you have your linux box ready.

Comment: Are there Kodi plugins for those sites as well ? Is kodi v18.7 enough ? However, my linux box is not ready yet and I have to go. Let me recontact you tonight.